# Rails link_to issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make my rails application generate a link without the text and custom content instead. I am currently doing this

```
<%= link_to '', {:controller => :project, :action => :show}, {:id => project.id, :class => "projects"} do %>
<div class="image-container">
  <%= image_tag project.images[0].image.url, :title => project.title  %>
</div>
<p>
  <span class="title">
    <%= project.title %>
  </span>
  <span class="summary">
    <%= project.summary %>
  </span>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Which generates this code

```
<a action="show" controller="project" href>
<div class="image-container">
  <img alt="House 2" src="/uploads/project_image/image/1/house-2.jpg" title="Ygfaweg">
</div>
<p>
  <span class="title">

  </span>
  <span class="summary">

  </span>
</p>
</a>
```

The link is incorrect and is missing alot of data, any idea why?

Comment: Can you show us, what the `project` is in this code?

Comment: @PeterTretyakov the project is a controller class, i have noticed that i also have a project model, could that interfere with that?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed that did not work, <a action="show" class="projects" controller="project" href="#" id="1">
Is that link it generated.

Comment: I meant, that `<%= project.title %>` doesn't renders in your code. It can be, because of `title` is empty. So, I want to understand if `project.title` is empty or there is another bug in code.

Comment: project.title is valid and it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `''` from `link_to` method.
2. Change `:controller` in `link_to` method to `projects`
3. Remove braces from `:id => project.id, :class => "projects"`

So, refactor the first line to:

```
<%= link_to {:controller => :projects, :action => :show}, :id => project.id, :class => "projects" do %>
```

Comment: <%= link_to {:project, :action => :show}, :id => project.id, :class => "projects" do %>

This resolves in a big error.

 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}' ...fer.append= link_to {:project, :action => :show}, :id => pr

Answer (score 0):

I didnt come to a pure conclusion with this issue. I ended up doing this which works fine.

```
<a class="project" href="<%= url_for({:controller => :project, :action => :show, :id => project.id}) %>">
```

Cheers everyone!

Comment: Are you using rails 4? It should just be `<%= link_to "", project_path(project), class: "project" %>`. Why are you using this old syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this :

```
<%= link_to ({:controller => :project, :action => :show,:id => project.id}, {:class => "projects"}) do %>
   <div class="image-container">
     <%= image_tag project.images[0].image.url, :title => project.title  %>
  </div>
  <p>
    <span class="title">
      <%= project.title %>
    </span>
    <span class="summary">
      <%= project.summary %>
    </span>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove blank string from link_to and you are done.

```
<%= link_to {:controller => :project, :action => :show}, {:id => project.id, :class => "projects"} do %>
<div class="image-container">
  <%= image_tag project.images[0].image.url, :title => project.title  %>
</div>
<p>
  <span class="title">
    <%= project.title %>
  </span>
  <span class="summary">
    <%= project.summary %>
  </span>
</p>
<% end %>
```